# SWIFT iOS 11 - NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0] returns en in Simulator and en_US on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, locale

I'm testing the localization of our iOS 11 app and found that `NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0]` returns `'en'` when I run the app in the Simulator on my Laptop. However when I run the app on the iPhone the same call returns `'en_US'`.

Has anybody encountered the same behavior? Is there a way to make both Simulator and Phone return the same value (preferably `'en_US'`)?

Comment: Are you aware that you can test languages and locales with the `-AppleLanguages` and `-AppleLocale` launch arguments in the scheme editor?

Comment: I've looked into those but I don't see why the Simulator would return a different value than the phone...

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I always got last selected language